# Stress Test server handle request

Tags: multithreading, yii, request, connection-pooling

First, I want to stress test my server [`xeon(2x)2.53ghz, 4gb ram`] [`build by Yii`], a stable condition with:
1- Create new recorde -- about 200
2- Update database -- about 250 
 3- Query database -- about 300 
 If I use range of request over that numbers I get status of request is `null`.
And I have another test `don't use db` [it just send a post name to server and server `echo` something] -- I sent about 1000 threads request just the number of successful request about 800 and the remainder is `null`. 
So, everbody please help me, about the number of request is that suitable or it's very low, and how to overcome `null` request response 
[`tool test: I built a simple project by objective-C`]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried `ab` ? the Apache Benchmarking tool ?

```
$ ab -n 200 -c 5 http://myhost/the/page/that/creates/the/records
$ ab -n 250 -c 5 http://myhost/the/page/that/updates/the/records
$ ab -n 300 -c 5 http://myhost/the/page/that/queries/the/records
```